# Scala: Declare val in if condition

Tags: scala

I have very generic use case. I have a method `conditionMethod` which return Int

```
def conditionMethod(..):Int = {..}
```

Now I have if condition using same method

```
if (conditionMethod(..) > 0){
  conditionMethod(..) + 23 // Any action
}
```

Problem is it is calling method conditionMethod two times. To solve this, another approach is

```
val tmp = conditionMethod(..)
if (tmp > 0){
  tmp + 23 // Any action
}
```

What I don't like in this is I have to define a variable with larger scope.

Can I do something like

```
if ((val tmp = conditionMethod(..)) > 0){  // tmp variable in if condition itself 
  tmp + 23 // Any action
}
```

Scala version: 2.11

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can keep the scope really tight:

```
val result = {
  val tmp = methodCall()
  if (tmp>0) tmp else tmp+23
}
```

Or use `match`

```
methodCall() match {
   case x if x <= 0 => x + 23
   case x => x
}
```

Comment: thanks for quick comment.  I have one question. Using match for just one condition looks to me little bit complicated. Is it right practice to use match for same?

Answer (score 7):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, the chaining operation [`pipe`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/util/ChainingOps.html#pipe[B](f:A=%3EB):B) can be used to convert/pipe a value with a function of interest, and thus avoids an intermediate variable:

```
import scala.util.chaining._

13.pipe(res => if (res > 0) res else res + 23 ) // 13
```

This is actually a very close variant of a `match` statement and can as well be written as such:

```
-27 pipe { case res if (res > 0) => res case res => res + 23 } // -4
```

Answer (score 3):

You could `fold` over a single element collection.

```
Seq(conditionMethod(..)).fold(0){case (z,x) =>
  if (x>z) x+23  // any action as long as the result is an Int
  else     x
}
```

If your "action" doesn't result in an `Int` then you could use `foldLeft`. Here's the same thing returning a `String`.

```
Seq(conditionMethod(..)).foldLeft(""){case (_,x) =>
  if (x>0) {
    x+23  // any action as long as if/else types match
    "string"
  }
  else "xxx"
}
```